# Adding Leading Zeros to a field with MM:SS time data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

data shows a race time finish and pace:
[image: data shows a race time finish and pace]

As you can see, the data doesn't show the hour format for people who finish before the hour mark and in order to do some analysis, i need to convert into a time format but pandas doesn't recognize just the MM:SS format. how can I pad '0:' in front of the rows where hour is missing?

i'm sorry, this is my first time posting.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the input dataframe in text form? (You can use `Ctrl`+`K` for formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your data is in csv format.

```
# reading in the data file
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')

# replacing spaces with '_' in column names
df.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    val_inital = str(row.Gun_time)
    val_final = val_inital.replace(':','')
    if len(val_final)<5:
        val_final = "0:" + val_inital
        df.at[i, 'Gun_time'] = val_final

# saving newly edited csv file
df.to_csv('new_data_file.csv')
```

**Before:**

```
  Gun time
0    28:48
1    29:11
2  1:01:51
3    55:01
4  2:08:11
```

**After:**

```
  Gun_time
0  0:28:48
1  0:29:11
2  1:01:51
3  0:55:01
4  2:08:11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply the following function to the columns you want to change then maybe change it to timedelta

```
df['Gun time'].apply(lambda x: '0:' + x if len(x) == 5 \
    else ('0:0' + x if len(x) == 4 else x))

df['Gun time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Gun Time'])
```